# Why does a line rotate clockwise when you substitute a counter-clockwise rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations

The point $(x, y)$ can be rotated by $\theta$ in a **counter-clockwise** direction about the origin $(0, 0)$. This point $(x', y')$ can be found by using the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions), as so:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
   cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) \\
   sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\ y'
\end{bmatrix}
$
That is,

$
\begin{aligned}
x' & = x\cos(\theta) - y\sin(\theta) \\
y' & = x\sin(\theta) + y\cos(\theta)
\end{aligned}
$

Given the equation of a line

$Ax + By = C$

To rotate this line by $\theta$ in a **counter-clockwise** direction about the origin, one would think that you would simply substitute $(x', y')$ into the equation, giving you:

$A (x\cos(\theta) - y\sin(\theta)) + B (x\sin(\theta) + y\cos(\theta)) = C$

or with collected x and y terms:

$x(A\cos(\theta) + B\sin(\theta)) + y(B\cos(\theta) - A\sin(\theta) = C$

However, **this is not the case**, I now realise that this actually rotates it in a **clockwise** direction, but I don't understand **why**.

Can anyone explain why this is the case? I feel that it has something to do with the form with collected x and y terms, due to it resembling the transpose of rotation matrix multiplied by $[A, B]^T$, but to me that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You need to be clear on whether what you are rotating is your space, or the coordinate grid you are using to describe your space. If you turn the grid clockwise, then the apparent effect will be that the space rotates counterclockwise.

Comment: Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Think about how the graph of $f(x - c)$ is the graph of $f(x)$ moved to the *right* by $c$, not to the left. This is because $f(x-c)$ attains the value $f(x_0)$ at $(x_0 + c) - c$, so the entire function is displaced to the right. Similarly here, by substituting $(x', y')$ into the line equation, the point $(x_0, y_0)$ satisfying the line equation is actually attained for $(x_0, y_0)$ rotated clockwise by $\phi$, effectively rotating the entire line clockwise by $\phi$.

Comment: @mechanodroid I think your explanation makes more sense to me than the others, thanks. I'd be happy to accept it if you post an answer.

Comment: @miguel.martin I added the answer, glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Think about how the graph of $f(x−c)$ is the graph of $f(x)$ moved to the *right* by $c$, not to the left. This is because $f(x−c)$ attains the value $f(x_0)$ at $x_0+c$:

$$f((x_0 + c) - c) = f(x_0)$$
so the entire function is displaced to the right.

Similarly here, by substituting $(x',y')$ into the line equation, the point $(x_0,y_0)$ satisfying the line equation is actually attained for $(x_0,y_0)$ rotated clockwise by $\phi$.
This is effectively rotating the entire line clockwise by $\phi$.

Answer (score 3):

Your transformation expresses the new coordinates $x'$, $y'$ in terms of the old coordinates $x$, $y$.

On the other hand, in order to find the image of the rotated line in the new coordinate system, you must substitute to the old coordinates $x, y$ appearing in its equation their expressions in terms of the new coordinates $x'$, $y'$.

In other words, you must apply the *inverse* of the tranformation you are considering.

Answer (score 1):

To explain Francesco Polizzi's comment in a symbolic way that I find more satisfying: let's say you have a set $S$ in the plane defined by the equation $f(x) = 0$, and you'd like to know its image $TS$ under the invertible transformation $T$. The image in question, in symbols, is $$\{T(x, y) | f(x, y) = 0\}.$$

This is equivalent (writing $(x', y') = T(x, y)$) to $$\{(x', y') | f( T^{-1}(x', y') ) = 0\}.$$

In your case, if $S$ is your original line $Ax + By = C$ and $TS$ is the line rotated counter-clockwise, the equation for $TS$ is such that if you apply a clockwise transformation to the coordinates in the equation (thereby taking $TS$ to $S$), you recover the equation for $S$.